# Optional Grid in Overlay

Tags: grid-layouts, overlay

i have this code:

```
With[{
img = ImageResize[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}], {escala}]},
   size = 1000;
    escala = 500;
     proporcion = size/escala;

  celda = 200;
n = size/celda;
sub = Subdivide[-1, 1, n];

With[{
    dimensions = ImageDimensions[img]},
        Manipulate[

    grid = 
Graphics[{}, GridLines -> {sub, sub}, PlotRangePadding -> None, 
 GridLinesStyle -> 
  Directive[White, Thick, Dashing[Tiny], Opacity[0.5]], 
 ImageSize -> ImageDimensions@img];
    Overlay[{img, grid}],

   {{pt, dimensions/2}, Locator, Appearance -> disk[r, White, pt]},
   {{pt2, dimensions/2}, Locator, Appearance -> disk[r, Red, pt2]},

{{r, .05, Style["r", Bold, 15]}, .02, .5, .01, ImageSize -> 500},
ControlPlacement -> Top, 
Initialization :> (disk[r_, color_, pt_] := 
  Graphics[{{Opacity[.4, color], EdgeForm[Black], 
     Disk[{0, 0}, Scaled[r]]}, {Thick, 
     Line[{Scaled@{.5 - r/8, .5}, Scaled@{.5 + r/8, .5}}], 
     Line[{Scaled@{.5, .5 - r/8}, Scaled@{.5, .5 + r/8}}]}, {Text[
      Framed[Style[Row[pt, ","], Bold, 12], FrameMargins -> Tiny, 
       Background -> Opacity[.4, White]], Scaled@{.5, .52 + r}]}},
    ImageSize -> dimensions])]]]
```

I want to make the GRID optional but i don't know how to enable/disable it in real-time in the Overlay function.

I was thinking about a tick 0->ON 1->OFF, but the real problem is adding this inside Overlay itself.

Comment: Wrap it in an appropriate `Manipulate`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `GridLines` setting to

```
GridLines -> If[showGridlines, {sub, sub}, None]
```

and add the control

```
{showGridlines, {True, False}}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: It works good =) thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since you seem to have most of the details worked out with respect to your image and gridlines, I'll only give a minimal working example for the checkbox.

I would move to a dynamic module and use the switch to either output the image or the image with the overlay:

```
DynamicModule[{swtch},
 img1 = Graphics[{Red, Disk[{0, 0}, 0.5]}];
 img2 = Graphics[{Blue, Rectangle[]}];
 Panel[Column[{
  Labeled[Checkbox[Dynamic@swtch], "Optional Overlay"],
  Dynamic@If[
    swtch,
    Overlay[{img2, img1}],
    img2
    ]
  }]
 ]
]
```

[image]

Comment: any other way? i can't introduce it inside the with and manipulate.